# Simple custom jbuilder json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I'd like to be able to create some super simple json string with jbuilder since it's included in rails 4 by default.

Say I got some Categories `current_project.categories`.

At the moment I'm using this jbuilder construct to get only the category titles:

```
json.array! current_project.categories do |c|
  json.title c.title
end
```

This genervtes the following response:

```
[{"title":"Allgemeine Fragen"},{"title":"Dauerkarten"},{"title":"Heimspiele"},{"title":"Online-Ticketing"},{"title":"Rollstuhlfahrer"},{"title":"Auswärtsspiele"},{"title":"Busfahrten"},{"title":"Meine Kategorie"},{"title":"Meine neue Kat"}]
```

It would be nice if I could keep that json response way more simple, e.g.:

```
["Allgemeine Fragen", "Dauerkarten", "Heimspiele", "Online-Ticketing", "Rollstuhlfahrer", "Auswärtsspiele", "Busfahrten", "Meine Kategorie", "Meine neue Kat"]
```

How can I accomplis this using jbuilder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
json.array! current_project.categories.pluck(:title)
```

or the extended version

```
json.array! current_project.categories.map(&:title)
```

The first is more efficient.

Comment: It's not pluck, it's the way you pass the argument to array! I've updated the question with a comparison.