# Rails: Using JBuilder views outside of the view context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am currently switching `ActiveModelSeralizer` to `JBuilder` for rendering jsons. I was wondering, with `ActiveModelSeralizer` I can do something like:

```
text_content = UserSeralizer.new(user, :root => false)
```

And receieve the json string in the variable called `text_content`. Now that I am switching away from ActiveModelSeralizer, is there anyway to do the above with JBuilder?

I have a view partial inside of `app/view/api/v1/users/_user.json.jbuilder` Is there anyway to render that partial into a variable?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to assign JSON to a text_content?

Answer (score 27):

Yes, you can. Just use `Jbuilder.encode` method:

```
# somewhere in User model

def display_to_json
  Jbuilder.encode do |json|
    json.name name
    json.location display_location
    json.description description
    json.work_experience work_experience
  end
end
```

and use it:

```
<!-- somewhere in view, just for example -->
<div ng-init="user = <%= @user.display_to_json %>"></div>
```

**Notice** : The class name is `Jbuilder`, not `JBuilder`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the posted question. It redefines a json representation inside the block and does **not** make use of a present jbuilder template.

Answer (score 5):

```
  json = ActionController::Base.new.view_context.render(partial: "api/v1/users/user", locals: {user: @user})
```

Comment: You could also use ```ApplicationController.render(partial: 'my_partial', locals: { my_obj: SomeObj })``` if you want to use helpers inside the partial.

Comment: It answers the question albeit being a bit of a long line for a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

"I have a view partial inside of app/view/api/v1/users/_user.json.jbuilder Is there anyway to render that partial into a variable?"

How about

```
json.partial! 'api/v1/users', users: @users.all
```

This will render the partial and create a new variable, users, with the contents @users.all

Answer (score 0):

In the Controller I used

> render json: whatever

Example:

1. In `items_controller.rb` (btw I used MongoDB):

> ```
> def show
>   render json: @item
> end
> ```

2. And `http://localhost:3000/items/` he replies me with the JSON:
   [image]

I have not used any views

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
text_content = json.(user, :id, :name, :published_at)
```

[jbuilder Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder?view=asciicast)

[jbuilder response as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705271/simple-custom-jbuilder-json-response)

For Render you can use this code:

```
json.partial! 'api/v1/users', users: @users.all
```

[json render for partial](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)